# Position of r before and after k in Sort

Tags: command-line, sort

I have tried the following two scripts to sort a CSV file

```
$ sort -t"," -k1,1 -k3,3 -k4,4 -k6,6r myFile.csv
```

and

```
$ sort -t"," -k1,1 -k3,3 -k4,4 -rk6,6 myFile.csv
```

I found having the **-r** before the **-k** reverse not only the 6th column but also the first column while keeping **-r** after **k** reverse only the 6th column. For one, I do not understand why putting **-r** before and after **-k** makes a difference. Also, I cannot find an explanation in **help** or **man**.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `-rk6,6`, the `-r` option is applied globally i.e. to all keys. It's like doing:

```
sort -t"," -r -k1,1 -k3,3 -k4,4 -k6,6 myFile.csv
```

On the other hand, `-k6,6r` will apply `r` to the sixth field only i.e. it is applied individually.

Answer (score 1):

As the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sort.1posix.html) says:

```
Sort keys can be specified using the options:

-k  keydef
      The keydef argument is a restricted sort key  field  definition.
      The format of this definition is:

      field_start[type][,field_end[type]]

where  field_start  and  field_end  define  a key field restricted to a
portion of the line (see the EXTENDED DESCRIPTION section), and type is
a  modifier  from  the list of characters 'b' , 'd' , 'f' , 'i' , 'n' ,
'r' .
```

`-k` is a *restricted* definition. The options you specify after `-k` are for that field definition only. `-r` on the other hand, is a global option. Again quoting the manpage:

```
The following options shall override the default ordering  rules.  When
ordering  options  appear  independent of any key field specifications,
the requested field ordering rules shall be  applied  globally  to  all
sort  keys.  When  attached  to  a specific key (see -k), the specified
ordering options shall override all global ordering  options  for  that
key.
```